# how can i stop my RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED service

Tags: android, service

seeing many questions about this but im unable to fix this.

I have this code

```
public class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String TAG = "myBroadcastReceiver";
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(intent.getAction().equals(Consts.ANDROID_INTENT_ACTION_BOOT_COMPLEATE)){
    Intent newinIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceBootCompleated.class);
    context.startService(newinIntent);
     }
  }
}
```

It starts a `Service` and i can debug it using this line

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

I see that `return START_NOT_STICKY;` is executed but still
the service is visible as a "running" service in the 
Setttings>programs>Running Services

the `onDestroy()` is never called unless i stop it manually.
What do i have to do to stop it,
remove it from "Setttings>programs>Running Services " window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have completed the work you wanted to do in the background call `stopSelf()`

Be sure that any real work you do in the Service is done as a background thread and not in onCreate or onStartCommand.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle for more details on the Service Lifecycle.

Example:

```
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId)
{       
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
                    //do work
                stopSelf();
        }
    },"MyWorkerThread");
    thread.start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I do call stopSelf() and the work is running in the onStartCommand. The code is just a few lines checking MySql integrity. I will move it to a thread. Thanks

Comment: Should i put the stopSelf(); in the onStartCommand after thread.run();? Or in the run() like this ctx.stopSelf();

Comment: It may be that calling stopSelf in onStartCommand (from main thread) is inconsistent because the Service isn't considered started until onStartCommand returns. I'm usually calling it from another thread on completion of the work.

Comment: Or subclass the existing IntentService, it will stop itself when you've completed your task.

Answer (score 0):

on completion of task, you have to do context.stopService() for stopping this type of unbound service.

Regards,
SSuman185