# How to stop service itself?

Tags: android, service, int

I have for example some int `myInt` in a service and if `myInt =`1 I'd like to stop service itself. So service should stop automatically.

```
@Override 
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
              if(myInt==1){
                 // need code for stopping service here
              }
        }
```

Comment: Ok I think you are gonna have to post the code where u start the service from ur activity.. @Adam

Comment: have you tried  stopSelf() in onStart() or onStartCommand() method if not try this.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Apparently we cannot stop a service due to the nature of the Service life cycle. if you can check your condition also in  [OnStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29), Can you try calling stopself() there ?

**UPDATE 2**

For sample code : you can try running the `stopSelf()` on a seperate thread as in this post : [how can i stop my RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845941/how-can-i-stop-my-receive-boot-completed-service)

Comment: Yes, this onCreate of the service. I tried to put stopSelf() to my code, yesterday, but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to add my if condition to OnStartCommand and if condition was accepted I tried to call stopSelf(), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I always start service from other Activity and if two int values are = 1(firstInt==1 && secondInt==1) I need to stop service, but I need to stop it from service, because if I stopped it from that Activity I'd add really lots of codes. Stopping it from service is the best solution for me. Could you give me some code example, how can I do it, please?

Comment: 1) I think you should add some details of where / how you start the service in the first place?
2) `stopSelf()` may not immediately return and stop the service. How do you check if ur service is still running or not? What makes you think "it doesnT work" ?

Comment: I gave you a details, I started my service from other Activity, then I have used onCreate method in my Service which you can see up in my question. My service always runs when people activate it with button. But I need to know how can I stop it. And it doesn't work, because service is still running, I checked it with Manage apps.

Comment: I tried to manage code from that answer, but still service is running.

Comment: Man! :) ... it s a tricky thing this service. Does it _ever_ stop (and you are not satisfied about the timing) or is `stopSelf()` totally ignored?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7060/discussion-between-zortkun-and-adam)

Answer (score 0):

use "this.stopSelf()":

```
@Override 
public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
          if(myInt==1){
             this.stopSelf();
          }
    }
```

IF the service isnt kept alive by still being bound AND/OR by having been started as a STICKY (START_STICKY), this will work.